# angularjs how to remove duplicates by multiple select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

a question to angular js. Let's say I have an array of objects eg:

```
items = [
{"id":1,"name":"AAA"},
{"id":2,"name":"BBB"},
{"id":3,"name":"CCC"},
{"id":4,"name":"DDD"}
]
```

Now I have 2 or 3 selects in my view.

```
<select type="text" class="form-control form-control-small" 
ng-model="itemId" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items">
</select>

<select type="text" class="form-control form-control-small" 
ng-model="itemId" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items">
</select>

<select type="text" class="form-control form-control-small" 
ng-model="itemId" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items">
</select>
```

So how can I assure that I have all 4 options in the first select, 3 options in the second one (all minus selected), two in the third one (also all minus selected) and so on. 
And how can I update the subsequent selects whenever there is a change in any of the selects.

Many thanks in advance for ideas.

Comment: question is not clear. please edit it, or post a fiddle demonstrating it.

Comment: May i ask why do you need this functionality? Maybe multiselect will be enought?

Comment: I just have such a requirement, I'd like to do it with multiselect, but this solution is impossible for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a filter.
*Note: I am using the ES5 filter function, it won't work on IE8 unless your use a shim*

```
yourModule.filter('exclude', function () {
    return function (items, exclude) {
        return items.filter(function (item) {
            return exclude.indexOf(item.id) === -1;
        });
    });
});
```

And in your markup

```
<select type="text" class="form-control form-control-small" 
ng-model="itemId1" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items">
</select>

<select type="text" class="form-control form-control-small" 
ng-model="itemId2" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items | exclude:[itemId1]">
</select>

<select type="text" class="form-control form-control-small" 
ng-model="itemId3" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items | exclude:[itemId1, itemId2]">
</select>
```

If you want to update your selects if there is a change in the first or second one, use `ngChange` directive for resetting or changing other model values.

Comment: The solution will be probably sth like this, but I can not name my ng-model like "id1", "id2". I add the new select dinamically on demand so every "row" has the same model

Comment: exclude.indexOf(item) === -1; in this line it should be exclude.indexOf(item.id) as we are matching ids and not entire item @Thomas Roch

Comment: Thanks @mohamedrias but no need for you to copy paste.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. Anyway I was able to change the requirements so I run it with multiselect :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Module.filter('exclude', function () {
    return function (items, exclude) {
        return items.filter(function (item) {
            return exclude.indexOf(item.id) === -1; // Checking if the itemid is present already in the array
        });
    }
});
```

And in your markup

```
<select type="text" class="form-control form-control-small" 
ng-model="itemIdA" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items">
</select>

<select type="text" class="form-control form-control-small" 
ng-model="itemIdB" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items | exclude:[itemIdA]">
</select>

<select type="text" class="form-control form-control-small" 
ng-model="itemIdC" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items | exclude:[itemIdA, itemIdB]">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a better (imho) solition. We just add a boolean field to the array, like:

```
{"id":1,"name":"AAA", "show" : true}
```

and filter to ng-options:

```
 ng-options="item as item.name for item in items | filter : {"show : true}"
```

When selecting an item from the list we need to update to "show" value to false, so it won't be visible on the next select and update again to value true when when it is necessary. 
Anyway thx a lot for your help :)